# Creating a function to return either a 1 or a 0 based on a defined percentage

Tags: delphi

I cannot seem to figure out how to define a percent "chance" of returning a result.

For example,

```
Function roll(Percent:integer):string;
var
  I:integer;
Begin 
  I := Random(Percent);
  If I = 25 then
    result := 'win'
  else 
    result := 'lose';
End;
```

But actually having Roll(60); have a 60% chance of returning win. Is there any way this can be accomplished?

Apologies for the likely incorrect formatting, and the poor example of what I am trying to accomplish, but any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if Random < Percent / 100 then Result := 'Win' else Result := 'Lose'`. Please notice the spelling of "lose".

Comment: By the way, have you tried to analyse your code yourself? When you read the documentation, you learned that `Random(Percent)` returns a random integer between `0` and `Percent - 1`. So, for instance, if `Percent = 10`, you get a random integer between `0` and `9`. Now, a random integer between `0` and `9` is *never* going to be equal to `25`, so clearly you will lose every time.

Comment: I propably would have used something like `if Random(100) < Percent then result := 'win' else result := 'lose';` so that `0..59` are wins and `60..99` are loses.